# R: How can I replace the decimal characters in my dataset?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with `log10()` and struggle with transforming my dataset so that it works.

My dataset looks somewhat like this:

```
question_ID estimate
1   1   15000088
2   1   2,00E+07
3   1   1.2e+07
4   2   4.3e+07
5   2   6,00E+08
6   2   14500000
7   3   3500000
8   3   8,00E+06
9   3   1.2e+07
```

I want to run this syntax:

```
m <- dt %>% group_by(question_ID) %>% summarize(m=median(log10(estimate)))
```

and get the error:

```
Error in Math.factor(estimate) : ‘log10’ not meaningful for factors
```

I checked with `sapply(dt, class)` and know that `estimate` is a factor. 
I think the problem is that some values are written with `,` instead of `.`. Because `log10()` works with e.g. `8.5E+07` and `8.5e+07` but not `8,5E+07`.

How can I replace the decimal character?

I tried several things, but they all don't work.

```
dt$estimate <- gsub("\\.", ",", dt$estimate)
dt$estimate <- as.factor(dt$estimate)

format(dt, decimal.mark=".")
options(scipen = 999)
```

Comment: Try `dt$estimate <- as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", dt$estimate))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a factor to integer\numeric without loss of information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information)